# Interface for remote file operations?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm developing a service for EDI Operations between different systems and clients and thought it would be a smart approach, to use an interface for file operation services on remote servers. Say one remote server uses SFTP while the other FTP and another FTP(s) and so on.

The methods I'd need for every case would be the same basic set: ListDirectory(), UploadFile(), DownloadFile() etc.
And I like the idea of just implementing the interface on the client side and basically don't have to worry about the implementation anymore.

```
public interface IRemoteFileOperator
    {
        void CreateDirectory(string remotePath);
        void DeleteFile(string remotepath);
        void DeleteDirectory(string remotePath);
        void DownloadFile(string remotePath, string localPath);
        string[] ListDirectory(string remotePath);
        void UploadFile(string localPath, string remotePath);
    }
```

Now the Problem I have with this is, while for SFTPServiceProvider Class it's pretty basic, I struggle with different functionality of FTPServiceProvider Class.
Say I want to use "Passive FTP" or enable SSL in a specific case?

I don't want to write properties in the Interface like "EnableSSL" and "UsePassive", since other services like SFTP would not support them, making them useless.

I also don't like the idea to use them in the constructor of the FTPServiceProvider since I feel like they are not strictly "necessary" to make it work. Heck for anonymous FTP I'd be fine with just the hostname.

```
 public class FtpProvider : IRemoteFileOperator
    {     
        public FtpProvider(string serverUri, string user, string password)
        {
        //stuff
        }

        public FtpProvider(string serverUri, string user, string password, 
         bool useSSL, bool usePassive)
        {
        //stuff
        }
```

And I could chain the constructors for every possible combination, but that would make it very bloated in my opinion.

Now my questions are:

Is there a best practice for this?

Should I not use an Interface to begin with?

Should I not worry about a bloated constructor?

Is there another/better way to do it in the first place?

Comment: try code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

If you don't want to write many different constructors, even if this is the cleanest solution from my perspective, because you can define which combinations of parameters are valid, there are several possibilities to deal with it.

1. Use optional parameters, that can reduce the number of necessary constructors, e.g.:

   ```
   public FtpProvider(string serverUri, string user = null, string password = null, bool useSSL = false, bool usePassive = false)
   {
   //stuff
   }
   ```
2. Expose the parameters as public fields, then you can do the following to initialize the object:

   ```
   var remoteFileOperator = new FtpProvider(ftpUri)
   {
       user = "user1",
       password = "12345"
   };
   ```
3. There are other solutions like a fluent builder pattern, that can be nice to use, but require a lot more implementation...

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot.
I did not know you can do 1. and 2. so this was quite eye opening!